# Why do i have to put button commands as lambda functions?

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, window

I was watching [this](https://youtu.be/5UQZNHlaUVc) tutorial on how to create a GUI calculator. I don't understand why he puts button commands as lambda functions. Aren't they already functions?

```
button3 = Button(frame, text=3, height=4, width=9, font=35,
                 command= lambda: button_press(3))
button3.grid(row=0, column=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why do i have to put button commands as lambda functions?

You don't have to use lambda. If you don't need to pass arguments you can use a reference to a function that takes no parameters. However, if you want to pass arguments then you'll have to do something that allows you to use parameters.  `lambda` isn't the only solution, it is just one of the most convenient.

You could also use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) or some other technique such as a unique function for every button.